# What does @foo || @foo = "bar" mean in Ruby and why?

Tags: ruby

What does `@foo || @foo = "bar"` mean in Ruby? To me, it seems to have the meaning of `@foo || (@foo = "bar")` instead of `(@foo || @foo) = "bar"`. This, however, contradicts with the fact that [`||` has a higher precedence than `=` in Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

I am aware that `||` in Ruby is a short-circuit operator. I also understand that `||` is to be evaluated before `=` according to precedence. What I don't understand is that `@foo = "bar"` seems to be the right operant of `||`. According to the [precedence table](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html), the right operant of `||` should be @foo, and the expression should be equivalent to `(@foo || @foo) = "bar"`, which is illegal.

Comment: How is it contradictory? If `@foo` is truthy the `||` will short-circuit and the result of the expression will be `@foo`. If it’s falsey the bit on the right of the `||` is evaluated, `@foo` is assigned, and the result of the expression is ultimately `”bar”‘.

Comment: It's also often written as `@foo ||= "bar"`, i.e., assign `"bar"` to `@foo` only if `@foo` is `nil` or `false`.

Comment: @pjs Yes, it is abbreviation  to use it as logical assignment for `@foo = @foo || nil` but you do not need to do same in case of assigning nil to instance variable having default as nil

Answer (score 1):

Ruby uses [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and so it evaluates the first argument to decide if it should continue with the second one.

In case of `@foo || @foo = "bar"`, OR operation is performed in such a way that when first argument is found nil, second argument is evaluated which is assignment statement. IF first argument is found/truthy then it will ignore second argument(statement in this case)
Note, it does not just assign value to `@foo`, complete logical statement return value after assignment.

If you write, `@foo = @foo || 'sd'` logical operation are performed first & then assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the end it truly is simply Short-circuit-evaluation as ray mentions in his answer, but I think the documentation is lacking in this regard.

`||` is a short-circuit operator so as evaluation proceeds left to right, as soon as it finds a true, it is done and will return true,  otherwise it will proceed to the right

the `modifier-if` (also listed on the page you linked to) has lower precedence than the assignment `=`,  however assignment is not a short-circuit operator, so code  like

```
foo = "not set"
is_true = false
foo = 42 if is_true
puts foo
```

will print

> > not set

while code such as:

```
foo = "not set"
is_true = true 
foo = 42 if is_true 
puts foo
```

will print

> > 42

`||` is a short-circuit operator so code such as this:

```
foo = 0 
foo || foo = 42
puts foo
```

will print

> > 0

because the left hand foo is not nil,  so there is no reason to evaluate the right hand side.

while code such as this:

```
foo = nil
foo || foo = 42
puts foo
```

will print

> > 42

since foo is nil, evaluation will continue to the right side of the `||` until it his a something that is true or return the last expression which will be true or false.

I agree however that the document you point to would imply that

`x || y = z` should be based on precedence could be interpreted as `(x || y) = z` which would not be legal.  However it's also obvious that this would be the same as trying to assign a value to a boolean.

For example:

```
(true || true) = 42
```

is a syntax error

as does:

```
a = nil
b = nil
(a || b) = 42
```

yet

```
a = nil
b = nil 
a || b = 42
puts b
```

results in

> 42

Answer (score 0):

Simply, your interpretation of the precedence rule is wrong.

Precedence rule applies when there is ambiguity. With assignment syntax, the left hand side of `=` has to be a single token that is legal as a constant or some type of variable.

```
@foo || @foo = ...
```

can be only interpreted as

```
@foo || (@foo = ...)
```

and there is no ambiguity here, hence no issue of precedence.

What the precedence rule is concerned with is the right hand side of `=`. It is saying that

```
@foo = bar || baz
```

is interpred as

```
@foo = (foo || baz)
```

and not

```
(@foo = foo) || baz
```